Segmenting all contours or a better approach for these pellets
I am attempting to find the governing equation for the Position(x,y,t) and Orientation θ(x,y,t) of these pellets, which collectively behave as a fluid. To perform flow analysis and find governing equations for these pellets (which will be accordingly moved across by a conveyor belt): PELLETS
I first attempted to do a Langrangian analysis of this problem, which required that I find every pellet and its position/center position (Xi) and Angle/orientation relative to the horizontal (θi). However so I did it, I used MATLAB and python modules such as OpenCV, I was not able to segment all the pellets to even make this a possibility.
CODE I USED:
clear
function [BW,maskedRGBImage] = mymask(RGB)
%createMask  Threshold RGB image using auto-generated code from colorThresholder app.
%  [BW,MASKEDRGBIMAGE] = createMask(RGB) thresholds image RGB using
%  auto-generated code from the colorThresholder app. The colorspace and
%  range for each channel of the colorspace were set within the app. The
%  segmentation mask is returned in BW, and a composite of the mask and
%  original RGB images is returned in maskedRGBImage.
% Auto-generated by colorThresholder app on 01-Apr-2024
%------------------------------------------------------
% Convert RGB image to chosen color space
I = rgb2hsv(RGB);
% Define thresholds for channel 1 based on histogram settings
channel1Min = 0.009;
channel1Max = 0.112;
% Define thresholds for channel 2 based on histogram settings
channel2Min = 0.103;
channel2Max = 0.275;
% Define thresholds for channel 3 based on histogram settings
channel3Min = 0.347;
channel3Max = 0.687;
% Create mask based on chosen histogram thresholds
sliderBW = (I(:,:,1) >= channel1Min ) & (I(:,:,1) <= channel1Max) & ...
    (I(:,:,2) >= channel2Min ) & (I(:,:,2) <= channel2Max) & ...
    (I(:,:,3) >= channel3Min ) & (I(:,:,3) <= channel3Max);
BW = sliderBW;
% Initialize output masked image based on input image.
maskedRGBImage = RGB;
% Set background pixels where BW is false to zero.
maskedRGBImage(repmat(~BW,[1 1 3])) = 0;
end
inpict = imread('test.png');
mk = mymask(inpict); % create a mask using global thresholds
mk = bwareaopen(mk,100); % get rid of a thousand tiny specks
S = regionprops(mk,'area');
CT = hsv(numel(S));
CT(2:2:end,:) = flipud(CT(2:2:end,:));
% the result is one giant conglomerate blob
% and several smaller conglomerate blobs
alpha = 0.8;
outpict = labeloverlay(inpict,bwlabel(mk), ...
    'transparency',1-alpha,'colormap',CT);
imshow(outpict,'border','tight')


RESULT IMAGE FOR THE LANGRANGIAN ATTEMPT USING MATLAB: ATTEMPT
The python attempt at segmentation was even worse
Attempting to track all pellets as a function of time is quite difficult. How can I use segmentation in order to properly segment all pellets, or is there a better way to find the center-position and angle of the pellets such that governing equations for each could be made?

Cool question, but too broad. I remember I answered one of your questions before. And I agree with Christoph that the question itself is not answerable, at least not on Stackoverflow, where people are doing their best to willingly contribute to solve some specific programming problems. What you are asking is indeed programming related, but it requires extensive domain knowledge and a lot of time.
